# What does this "send for" mean in the context

Tags: phrase-usage

First of all, I would like to thank you very much for your efforts and maintenance by promoters.

Now, I happened to have read an [article about the U.S diplomats issue](https://www.yahoo.com/news/raul-castros-surprising-response-harmed-us-diplomats-182555390.html), and the first line says,

> > The Cuban president **sent for** the top American envoy in the country to address grave concerns about a spate of U.S. diplomats harmed in Havana.

What I would like to ask you is, what kind of "role" could this for ( in bold ) be playing for?

Thank you so much in advance.

Sincerely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "**role**", but in serious diplomatic situations a host country may *summon* the representative of another country, usually the ambassador, to express the host country's concerns.

In your example, "**sent for**" means the host country, Cuba, has requested a meeting with the top American representative in Cuba, whow would be the ambassador since diplomatic relations were restored in 2015.

Comment: Thnak you for your answer. However, when you read the 3rd and 4th articles, which is , **But U.S. officials were caught off guard by the way he addressed the matter, devoid of the indignant, how-dare-you-accuse-us attitude the U.S. had come to expect from Cuba's leaders.

The Cubans even offered to let the FBI come down to Havana to investigate.**

Comment: Then I don't think for Cubans" to use this word to express "summoning"  is "well-equipped" to denote this scene.....

Comment: Why so? Summon = "call people to attend (a meeting)", though summon may have a stronger meaning than "**sent for**" (the latter leaving a greater possibility of being denied), obviously Castro was clearly intent on expressing the Cuban position on the situation.  One might expect the US to have summoned that Cuban ambassador to express their concern.

Comment: Thank you, now understand. Since the situation overthere is complicated, the article looks a bit strange too. haha.